# .sh script run by cronjob does not send email

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

I have a cronjob that runs an .sh script which should make a .txt file and send it as an email.

I use `sudo crontab -e`

Here is the script:

send_update.sh, -rwxrwxrwx

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/myusername/backend/mypy.py > update.txt
sed -i '1s/^/Subject: Daily Update /' update.txt
sendmail myemail@gmail.com < /home/myusername/backend/update.txt
echo "tester" >> tesert.txt
```

Interestingly, this file is properly run in that the echo does print to the file but I do not recieve an email.

If I run the file from the command line by typing `sudo ./send_update.sh` It does send an email.

**EDIT 1**

The cron file line looks like:

`*    *   *   *   *   cd /home/myusername/backend && ./send_update.sh`

**EDIT 2**

tesert.txt is in the same folder as send_update.sh and it does get printed into by the cron job

**EDIT 3**

All files involved have permissions: -rwxrwxrwx

**EDIT 4**

```
#!/bin/sh
python py2db.py > update.txt
sed -i '1s/^/Subject: Daily Update /' update.txt
sed -i '$ d' update.txt
date >> update.txt
sendmail myemail@gmail.com < update.txt
```

This is the new send_update.sh file. It successfully prints the most recent minute to update.txt every minute, but it never sends the email.

**EDIT 5**

As suggested I changed my file to

```
#!/bin/sh
python py2db.py > update.txt || echo "error python" >>/tmp/error.log
sed -i '1s/^/Subject: Daily Update /' update.txt || echo "error sed1" >>/tmp/error.log
sed -i '$ d' update.txt || echo "error sed2" >>/tmp/error.log
date >> update.txt || echo "error date" >>/tmp/error.log
sendmail myemail@gmail.com < update.txt || echo "error sendmail" >>/tmp/error.log
```

and after it runs `cat /tmp/error.log` reads `error sendmail`

**EDIT 6**

After looking through the logs I have found:

sendmail: not found

I am now trying to update the path to include sendmail. If anyone can direct me on how to do that it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 7**

changing `sendmail` to `/usr/sbin/sendmail` fixed the issue and the suggested error checking led me there.

Comment: check permissions; modify the script to use su - "user", where "user" is the same you use to run the script manually

Comment: When you run it by hand are you *in* the `/home/myusername/backend` directory? Because your cron job won't be. Why are you using an absolute path on just that one line?

Comment: @EtanReisner See my update

Comment: What user are you expecting that cron job to run under? What user is it actually running under? Does `sendmail` output anything to standard output or standard error? Do you have anything in your mail logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add debug to your script and log errors in a file, for example :

```
#!/bin/sh
python py2db.py > update.txt || echo "error python" >>/tmp/error.log
sed -i '1s/^/Subject: Daily Update /' update.txt || echo "error sed1" >>/tmp/error.log
sed -i '$ d' update.txt || echo "error sed2" >>/tmp/error.log
date >> update.txt || echo "error date" >>/tmp/error.log
sendmail myemail@gmail.com < update.txt || echo "error sendmail" >>/tmp/error.log
```

Maybe you don't have the path for one of your command, try to do an export PATH= too.